# Binary to Decimal in Python (Code modification to recursive?)

Tags: python, recursion, binary, decimal

Last week one of my homeworks was to program a Python method which one gets binary as array in parameters and then result returns the given binary to decimal.

I tried to figure out for recursive solution but time was running out for the deadline and didn't solved this one in recursive way. Perhaps solution is simple. How can I do this?

My final bet for the teacher's inbox was this piece of code:

```
def binToDec (arr):
    arr.reverse()
    result = 0
    for x in range(0,len(arr)):
        result+=arr[x]*pow(2,x)
    return result

arr = [1,1,0,0] 
result = binToDec(arr)
print (arr)
print (result)
```

Comment: It is OK to ask for homework help here. However, asking for someone to convert your code for an assignment is probably going to violate your academic honesty code **unless** you let your educator know that someone wrote the code for you. Even in those circumstances, is it not better to try something yourself?

Comment: I tried discover the recursive solution for that but deadline was reached and blamed the time out and after deadline was reached I decided to ask here. I¨m not one of those one who are crying somebody else to program my homeworks never.

Comment: I am pleased to hear that. Nevertheless, if you hand in one of the below solutions verbatim, you need to declare it to your educator. If you take one of the below solutions and modify it a bit and hand in the result, you need to declare it. Basically, it's OK to take help, but if you would be worried about declaring the amount of help you have taken - in case your educator would penalise you - then that is perhaps a sign that you need to assess your approach.

Answer (score 2):

All loops can be converted to tail recursion.

```py
def bin_to_dec(arr):
    if not arr:
        return 0
    return arr[-1] + (bin_to_dec(arr[:-1]) << 1)


print(bin_to_dec([1, 1, 0, 0]))
```

output:

```py
12
```

---

If you are confused with indexes, here is more readable code:

```py
def bin_to_dec(arr):
    if not arr:
        return 0
    *rest, lsb = arr
    return lsb + (bin_to_dec(rest) << 1)
```

same output with above.

Comment: What does `<<` do?

Comment: It is a shift operation. `x << 1` is almost same with `x * 2`. But in this case, we are going to handle binary bits, so I think `<< 1` is more intuitive than `* 2`.

Comment: How about using list -element instead of array? I read at https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/array that lists are faster than array to handle and work with. What comes to Algorithm Time Complexity when the developed system size increases it¨s more and more important to make decisions what saves resources like time and time means money in budget usually too. Perhaps it's same down here at my small  binToDec-func for thinking time complexity but it good to be in mind even small piece of excerices for future situations if I never will be the part of some real-world productive sw-team.

Comment: @Jere_Sumell We have used list. Just name was `arr` but type is `list`.

Comment: @Boseong Choi Apologies for that. Of course you are using list instead of array because this online discussion site is from programming experts and hobby enthusiastic and professional to the hobbyist and lifetime students and other professionals at top level even from higer level than top. As i commented earlier today other answer on this thread, I repeat: "I'm not fully fluent in using arrays in Python languuage." My comment about using list instead of array exposes that I'm really not have professional fluency in Python.I have humanist-approached way to study programming an to the technology

Comment: My Humanist-approached way to think and lifetime-studing technology and programming ends up some bad dilemmas sometimes but I don't care about it. I can handle my life and live with those demons. I started my academic studies after college with Educational Psychology and now I'm applying for the Art Academy degree program of Film-making despite of huge and increasing volume of applicants. I'm happy with my B.B.A passed degree in Information Technology and it good to have a programming hobby anyway.

Answer (score 1):

First, it is generally considered as bad practice to reverse the input array as a side effect. And `pow` is really overkill here. IMHO the iterative function would be more Pythonic that way:

```
def binToDec (arr):
    result = 0
    coeff = 1
    for x in reversed(arr):
        result+=x*coeff
        coeff *=2
    return result
```

The recursive way can be built simply by taking the least significant bit, and adding to it twice the value of the remaining of the array. In Python it just writes:

```
def recursBinToDec(arr):
    if 0 == len(arr):
        return 0
    else:
        return arr[-1] + 2 * recursBinToDec(arr[:-1])
```

Comment: Your "recursBinToDec" -method is nice piece of code! I¨ve not fully fluent in practical using of array to get maximum power of them in Python. Have to reread and study them for my future purposes. Your BinToDec -method is passing advanced course, I think equalled to my for loop-usage, it wasn't really advanced skill level -programming. My code down there looks like "Novice Level" This turning code from basic structures to advanced level by using power of tools offered by programming language added to common programming theory, makes programming just pure form of art. Interesting, good job!

Answer (score 0):

For a recursive code, check out this link https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursive-program-for-binary-to-decimal/

There is a pictorial representation which shows how we have to add all the values. Therefore, we take the current value, add it, then recur for remaining items.
The code on the link is pretty self-explanatory btw.

Comment: I read this geeksforgeeks -presnetation before my homework deadline but it¨s using strings as a input parameters and that¨s why I really did not give any weight for it for my needs. Thanks anyway for sharing! Appealing for this geeksforgeeks website domain-name choose: Many of those calling himself as "geeks", are more "Nerdy-like-guys" than pure Money-or Cash-driven in their mind when for example they are programming. I graduated from business bacleor -degree, but I¨m more technology - oriented than money-oriented in using computers.Still some of my friends call me "Geek".

Comment: Out of this thread have to comment: What comes to Geeks, Bill Gates is Geek over all the Time but Mark Zukenberg is The Geek of modern online world in 2020 turned the Legend in his lifetime as a "Young gun". Microsoft is perhaps most markable tech-company ever founded in the history of Man in my opinion and not only for the biggest wealth generated by man in the history. I like Zukenberg a lot  what he did and he have good pocket cards to grow his wealth even bigger if he stay tuned and develop security issues with his Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Python Program to Convert Decimal to Binary Check this blog https://www.techgeekbuzz.com/python-program-to-convert-decimal-to-binary-octal-and-hexadecimal/ Python Program to Convert Decimal to Binary is
dec_num = int(input("Enter the decimal value: "))
print(dec_num,"in Binary is:", bin(dec_num))

Output
Enter the decimal value: 8
8 in Binary is: 0b1000

and In python, Python Array does not have standard support for Array data structure, instead in python we often use the list data types to refer to an array. But there is a problem with lists, its violets the basic property of an array which is a homogeneous collection of elements. Though there is no in-built support for arrays in standard python, we can use a module name array to create an array data structure. visited this [site](https://www.techgeekbuzz.com/python-arrays/) for Learning Python Array.